# Angular router animation not triggering

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-animations

In my angular app I would like the router transitions be animated: the leaving component should fade-out and after that, the entering component should fade in. Basic stuff I would say :)

So I created [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e6qcuf?file=src%2Fapp%2Froute.animations.ts) (some of the code in there was copied from elsewhere), but my main resource was the [Angular Route transition animations](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations)

But, as you can see, for some reason the animations doesn't do anything.

Here is my animation code

```
export const routerTransition = trigger("routeAnimations", [
  transition("* => *", [
    query(":enter, :leave", style({ position: "fixed", width: "100%" })),
    query(":enter", style({ transform: "translateX(100%)" })),
    sequence([
      query(":leave", animateChild()),
      query(":leave", [
        style({ opacity: 1 }),
        animate(
          "1000ms cubic-bezier(.75,-0.48,.26,1.52)",
          style({ opacity: 0 })
        )
      ]),
      query(":enter", [
        style({ transform: "translateX(0)", opacity: 0 }),
        animate(
          "1000ms cubic-bezier(.75,-0.48,.26,1.52)",
          style({ opacity: 1 })
        )
      ]),
      query(":enter", animateChild())
    ])
  ])
]);
```

Also, here is the HTML from app.component, because thats the place where I connect the animation with the router

```
<main [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
    <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

And the prepareRoute looks like:

```
prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
   return (
     outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData.animation
   );
```

}

All according to the docs, so I'm a bit lost here with the animations so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your example

1. You're missing `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your `AppModule`. Consider adding it into `imports` section from `"@angular/platform-browser/animations"` package
2. If you check your `prepareRoute` function, you can see that it utilizes the `animation` property from the activated route data. The same is in the docs that you refer to. However, your route data is missing. Consider adding at least

   ```js
   {
      path: "foo",
      component: FooComponent,
      data: { animation: true }
   }
   ```

   to the foo path, and your animations start working.

Here you can find a [fixed example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rke77x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) however I'd advise you to check the docs more precisely because you can define animation names that you do not use for now.

Comment: @Jeanluca Scaljeri, let me know if my answer helps or you need some additional information

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to fix in in my App but still it didn't work. But eventually I noticed that [HotToastModule](https://github.com/ngneat/hot-toast) module breaks animation for some reason ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w7npqk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)) I'm going to file an issue for that library!